# Splitting flat data row into groupings

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a stored procedure that returns hierarchical data in a single long row, for example:

```
ContractID | ContractName | AssetID | AssetName | UnitID
-----------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------
2          | Test         | 7       | My asset  | 24
5          | Another one  | 51      | Vehicle   | 89
```

I need to create an SSRS report that displays the data hierarchically, like this:

```
ContractID | ContractName
2          | Test
    AssetID | AssetName
    7       | My asset
    UnitID
    24

ContractID | ContractName
5          | Another one
    AssetID | AssetName
    51      | Vehicle
    UnitID
    89
```

Being an SSRS n00b I'm stumped - is this even possible, and if so, how? If not, what is the best/recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: one long row with one column? or one row with multiple columns?

Comment: Essentially summarizing data from multiple tables into one long row with a couple dozen columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved this by using a subreport... nasty, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Assumes "one row with multiple columns" as per my comment

In your table:

- define a grouping on ContractID/ContractName
  Look for ["Adding Row Groups to a Table" in this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159169.aspx)
- I think you'll need to define another group on AssetID/AssetName
  I'm assuming multiple UnitID per AssetID/AssetName group
- UnitID is your detail group

Edit: Sorry: I've not yet worked with SSRS 2008 and Tablix controls.